# MySQL Order by another tables data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having difficulty understanding how to Order a query by data from another table.

The existing query is: `SELECT ID FROM UserTour WHERE Live = 1 ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC`

This obviously Orders by the column 'LastUpdated' in the table 'UserTour'

However, I need it to be ordered by the column 'LastUpdated' which is in another table 'ImageLinks', Where 'TypeID' = 16 (again in 'ImageLinks').

I hope that makes sense.

So it would be something like: `$ids = @mysql_values('SELECT ID FROM UserTour WHERE Live = 1 ORDER BY ('Select ID FROM 'ImageLinks' Where TypeID = 16 Order by LastUpdated DESC')');`

Any help would be appreciated on how to do this. Cheers

Comment: How are `UserTour` and `ImageLinks` connected?

Comment: Are there any common field or primary/foreign key relation between two tables?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: No I don't think they are connected. After the id's are got from UserTour table with the initial query above, a function then builds the 'User Tour' by fetching image ID's from the 'ImageLinks' table where TypeID=16 and LinkID = 'UserTourID'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no relationship between the two tables your query in your question will look like this

```
select id from
(
   SELECT 
        ID 
     , (Select ID FROM ImageLinks Where TypeID = 16 
        Order by LastUpdated DESC limit 1) as order_val
   FROM UserTour 
   WHERE Live = 1 
) x
ORDER BY x.order_val
```

which will work but will not do not any ordering as the `order_val` column will have a fixed value.

If the IDs are linked 1:1 (no indication that they are, but just supposin') we could do this:

```
select u.id 
from UserTour u inner join ImageLinks i on u.ID = i.ID
where u.Live = 1 and i.TypeID = 16
order by i.LastUpdated desc
```

If the above is incorrect then you will have to decide how the two tables are related and join them correspondingly.

***In other words***, If the tables are in no way connected, then you cannot provide an ordering of one table's data based on a column in the other.

**UPDATE**

```
select
     i.LinkID
   , i.LastUpdated 
from UserTour u inner join ImageLinks i 
on u.ID = i.LinkID 
where u.Live = 1 and i.TypeID = 16 
group by i.LinkID, i.LastUpdated
order by i.LastUpdated desc LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Thank you. I have it now working to a degree thanks to your help putting me on the right track, though it needs grouping somehow. This is what works - `$ids = @mysql_values('select u.id 
from UserTour u inner join ImageLinks i on u.ID = i.LinkID where u.Live = 1 and i.TypeID = 16  order by i.LastUpdated desc LIMIT 30');` though it needs grouping by u.linkID. I have tried adding Group by u.LinkID before the Order by, but it then does not order by correctly

Comment: @Treetops: please see my update. You have to have i.LinkID (or u.ID) **and** i.LastUpdated in the `group by` clause

Comment: Thanks Davek, that fixed it and it works perfectly now. Very much appreciated!